# Join/Merge Dataframe based on interval

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two tables: one is a table of planned leak patch, and the other is a table of realization of leak patched. Like follows:
[image]

The second table has more columns (omitted here). The case here is that i can join these two tables using SQL expression as follows:

```
SELECT
    PLAN.PIPE_ID,
    PLAN.INTERVAL_START,
    PLAN.INTERVAL_END,
    REAL.REAL_START,
    REAL.REAL_END,
    ...
FROM PLAN, REAL
WHERE
    PLAN.PIPE_ID=REAL.PIPE_ID
    REAL_START<INTERVAL_END AND
    REAL_END>INTERVAL_START AND
    ((REAL_START>=INTERVAL_START AND REAL_END<=INTERVAL_END) OR --CASE 1
    (REAL_START>=INTERVAL_START AND REAL_START>INTERVAL_END) OR --CASE 2
    (REAL_START<INTERVAL_START AND REAL_START<=INTERVAL_END) OR --CASE 3
    (REAL_START<INTERVAL_START AND REAL_START>INTERVAL_END)) --CASE 4
```

whence the cases of the condition are to suffice the description below and to make sure that the data displayed are only if the interval between two tables have intersection.[image: Intersection Cases]

If i were to make the same join using Pandas. How to do it? I am new to pandas, and i learned that Pandas join uses key(s).

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are six cases which range can intersect or not.  You have documented four cases, other two cases are one where REAL is completely before PLAN.  This condition can be tested by stating where REAL.REAL_END < PLAN.INTERVAL_START, and the other condition is where REAL is complete after PLAN. This condition can be tested by stating when REAL.REAL_START > PLAN.INTERVAL_END.

[image]  [image]

So, you can simply your SQL query to check this two conditions if neither is true then you have intersecting ranges.  In pandas, you can use the following, very similiar to what you are are doing in SQL, do a cross join and filter the results:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plan = pd.DataFrame({'PIPE_ID':['P_01','P_01'],'INTERVAL_START':[150,175],'INTERVAL_END':[151.5,177.5]})

real  = pd.DataFrame({'PIPE_ID':['P_01','P_01'],'REAL_START':[148,174.5],'REAL_END':[150.5,178]})

df_merged = plan.merge(real, on='PIPE_ID')

df_out = df_merged[~((df_merged['REAL_END'] < df_merged['INTERVAL_START']) | (df_merged['REAL_START']>df_merged['INTERVAL_END']))] 

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   INTERVAL_END  INTERVAL_START PIPE_ID  REAL_END  REAL_START
0         151.5             150    P_01     150.5       148.0
3         177.5             175    P_01     178.0       174.5
```